# Scraping elements inside a list in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-lists

I am completely new to scraping (and first post here) but using beautifulsoup i have managed to write code that outputs a list of scraped horse races for the entire day and outputs a list of them like the 1 race below for example:

```
<li class="w-racecard-grid-race-result" title="IRISH STALLION FARMS EBF TOTAL ENJOYMENT MARES I.N.H. FLAT (Listed)">
<a href="/horse-racing/result/fairyhouse/2023-04-08/1740/208/7">
<span><b>17:40</b> Bumper</span>
<span>2m 90y</span>
<span>Listed</span>
</a>
</li>
```

What I am trying to do is then export the time (in this example "17:40"), the race type (in this example "Bumper", the distance ("2m 90y") and title ("Listed"). Each horse race will follow the same above layout and I have tried a number of ways but so far no go. Normally (I assume) this could just be done by class or css selector but each span is related to ahref and css is the same for each part of it. I'm not sure if its possible to just select a particular span within that ahref, for example "span[0] = '17:40'" / "span[2] = 'Listed'" etc?? Even if this is possible the time ("17:40") is inside a < b > tag inside the first span along with the type ("Bumper")

I would like the output to be (which will be saved in a dataframe):

'Time: 17:40'
'Race Type: Bumper'
'Distance: 2m 90y'
'Title: Listed'

And this to be iterated over for each li in the whole list.

If possible I also need to take the URL and add a root url. I have tried to use urljoin but it doesn't like it as its mixing different strings / lists etc.

Any help would be great thank you.

My code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin

HTMLFileToBeOpened = open("timeform.html", "r")

contents = HTMLFileToBeOpened.read()

beautifulSoupText = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')

daily_racecard_info = beautifulSoupText.find(class_='w-racecard-grid-container widget-content widget-content-no-padding')

# Finds main body for INDIVIDUAL racecards
individual_course_racecard = daily_racecard_info.find_all(class_='w-racecard-grid-meeting')

# Finds course names for all
course_names = [item.find(class_='w-racecard-grid-course clickable').text.strip() for item in individual_course_racecard]

# Finds going for all courses
course_going = [item.find(class_='w-racecard-grid-info w-racecard-grid-info-going').text.strip() for item in individual_course_racecard]

# Removes word "going" from going
goings_simple = [item.replace('Going', '') for item in course_going]

# Gets individual race data (title, link, time, flat / hurdle / chase etc, distance and type)
individual_race_info = [item.find_all('li', class_='w-racecard-grid-race-result') for item in individual_course_racecard]
```

Comment: Seems like you could find all the `<li class="w-racecard-grid-race-result"` elements, then find all the `<span>` child elements of each `<li>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To extract the required information from the HTML using Beautiful Soup, you can use the 'find' method to find the 'a' tag within each 'li' tag, and then use the contents attribute to access the span elements within the a tag.

Here's some example code that should do what you need:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urljoin

# Example URL to scrape
url = "https://example.com/horse-racing"

# Get the page content and create a BeautifulSoup object
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

# Find all the race result li elements
race_results = soup.find_all("li", class_="w-racecard-grid-race-result")

# Create an empty list to store the data
data = []

# Loop over each race result
for result in race_results:
# Find the a tag within the li
a_tag = result.find("a")

# Extract the time and race type from the first span
time, race_type = a_tag.contents[0].text.split()

# Extract the distance from the second span
distance = a_tag.contents[1].text

# Extract the title from the third span
title = a_tag.contents[2].text

# Construct the full URL using urljoin
full_url = urljoin(url, a_tag["href"])

# Add the data to the list
data.append({
    "Time": time,
    "Race Type": race_type,
    "Distance": distance,
    "Title": title,
    "URL": full_url
})

# Convert the list of dicts to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the DataFrame
print(df)
```

The 'urljoin' function is used to construct the full URL for each race result            based on the root URL of the page.

Comment: Just wanted to come back and say thank you so much this does actually work but some of the coding required indents. Thank you so so much.